# Django page cache is caching header and footer

Tags: django, caching

I'm using django page cache decorator to cache only my homepage, because of this, the header and footer are also getting cached. So, if a request comes from different URL, it is picking the header and footer from cache only. As my header and footer is dynamic for different urls. So, some links are giving 404. Is there any way to solve this problem either by purging header and footer only or something better?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the [template fragment caching feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching):

> If you’re after even more control, you can also cache template fragments using the `cache` template tag. To give your template access to this tag, put `{% load cache %}` near the top of your template.
>
> The `{% cache %}` template tag caches the contents of the block for a given amount of time. It takes at least two arguments: the cache timeout, in seconds, and the name to give the cache fragment. The name will be taken as is, do not use a variable. For example:
>
> ```
> {% load cache %}
> {% cache 500 sidebar %}
>     .. sidebar ..
> {% endcache %}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the responses with fragment cache you have also django-phased wich is based on two-phase template rendering.

http://django-phased.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I am still also learning how to deal with caching with dynamic pages. I will tell what I think is the solution until someone better than me gives you a more experienced one.

You need to make your caching on the template level (more precisely you need to cache fragments of your templates).

Since your header and footer are dynamic, you can only cache the body fragment of your page. It can be done like:

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
{% cache 1000 'bodycache' %}
{% include 'body.html' %}
{% endcache %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

This will make every request to this view make all the sql queries required for the `header` and `footer`, but the `body` will be cached.